# html string tag from php to dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, dom

I retrieve this JSON from my database via PHP:

```
{
    "No. of Employees": "<span class=\"pull-right badge bg-blue\">Unlimited</span>",
    "Users": "<span class=\"pull-right badge bg-aqua\">Unlimited</span>",
    "No. of Clients": "<span class=\"pull-right badge bg-red\">N/A</span>",
    "No. of Stores": "<span class=\"pull-right badge bg-red\">N/A</span>"
}
```

Now, I have a list where I looped the json string on Laravel blade:

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked">
    @foreach($jsonstring as $key => $value)
        <li><a href="#">{{$key}} {{$value}}</a></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Here's my output before parsing HTML string to dom elements:

```html
No. of Employees <span class="pull-right badge bg-blue">Unlimited</span>
Users <span class="pull-right badge bg-aqua">Unlimited</span>
No. of Clients <span class="pull-right badge bg-red">N/A</span>
No. of Stores <span class="pull-right badge bg-red">N/A</span>
```

I have tried various approach like jquery's append and html tags (JS works but doesn't loop through the values), PHP's htmlentities, etc, (PHP doesn't work anyway) but haven't got cleaner approach to this.

On Jquery approach, I've tried this:

Stored value on a hidden field:

```
    <input type="hidden" class="infoval" value="{{$value}}"/>
```

Display result on div

```
<div class="infodisp"></div>
```

Then, parse html:

```
$('.infodisp').append($('.infoval').val());
```

This works but it doesn't go through the values. I haven't tried looping on jquery side. but I just need some clean way to parse the HTML strings to dom elements using jquery or PHP.

Thanks.